# not able to include altbeacon library into new project

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, altbeacon

I am trying to add an existing android library into my new fresh project. An existing library that I am using is `AltBeacon` library which I am able to compile it successfully.

After that, I have added `AltBeacon` library by importing as a model in my fresh new android project and added to my gradle. Now when I am trying to run the fresh project, I am getting following error.

I tried to explore almost all the threads on StackOverflow but not able to figure out what should I do to resolve it.

[image]

**For reference i am pasting `build.gradle` of `AltBeacon` library**

```
ext {
    isSnapshot = !project.hasProperty('release')
    isSnapCi = System.getenv('SNAP_CI') != null
    isSnapPullRequest = System.getenv('SNAP_PULL_REQUEST_NUMBER') != null
}

/*
 * Gets the version name from the latest Git tag
 */
def getVersionName = {
    def stdout = new ByteArrayOutputStream()
    try {
        exec {
            commandLine 'git', 'describe', '--tags'
            standardOutput = stdout
        }
        return stdout.toString().trim()
    }
    catch (e) {
        println("Can't get version from git: " + e);
        return "adhoc"
    }
}

buildscript {
    repositories {

        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com'
        }
        maven {
            url 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/'
        }
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
        classpath 'com.jfrog.bintray.gradle:gradle-bintray-plugin:1.7.3'
        classpath 'org.jfrog.buildinfo:build-info-extractor-gradle:3.0.3'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

apply from: 'gradle/eclipse.gradle'

allprojects {
    version = "${getVersionName()}${isSnapshot == true ? "-SNAPSHOT" : ""}"
    group = "org.altbeacon"

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com'
        }
        maven {
            url 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/'
        }
    }
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    buildToolsVersion '28.0.0'

    defaultConfig {
        // Unfortunately 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0'
        // requires minSdkVersion 14, forcing a bump verson minSdkVersion 7
        // But since only 0.8% of Android devices have < SDK 14 as of Une 2017, this will become
        // the new min version for this library in order to target Android O
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName version
        consumerProguardFiles 'proguard-rules.pro'
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    compileOptions {
        encoding "UTF-8"
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }

    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    }
}

configurations {
    doclava
}



dependencies {
    compile fileTree ( dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'] )
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0-rc02'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:28.0.0-rc02'

    testCompile 'com.google.android:android-test:4.1.1.4'
    testCompile('junit:junit:4.12') {
        exclude group: 'org.hamcrest'
    }
    testCompile('org.hamcrest:hamcrest-junit:2.0.0.0') {
        exclude group: 'junit'
    }
    testCompile('com.squareup:fest-android:1.0.+@aar')
    testCompile('org.robolectric:robolectric:3.0') {
        exclude group: 'junit'
    }
    testCompile('org.mockito:mockito-core:1.10.19') {
        exclude group: 'org.hamcrest'
    }
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
        exclude group: 'org.hamcrest'
    })
    androidTestCompile 'org.apache.commons:commons-math3:3.6.1'
    doclava 'com.google.doclava:doclava:1.0.6'
}

apply plugin: 'idea'

idea {
    module {
        testOutputDir = file('build/test-classes/debug')
    }
}

task renameAarForRelease(type: Copy, dependsOn: build) {
    description = "Rename the aar for easy release publishing"

    from "$buildDir/outputs/aar/" //${project.name}-release.aar
    into "$buildDir/outputs/aar/" //${project.name}-${project.version}.aar"
    include "${project.name}-release.aar"
    rename { String fileName ->
        fileName = "${project.name}-${project.version}.aar"
    }
}

task distribution(dependsOn: [bundleEclipse, build, clean, renameAarForRelease]) << {
    println "Building with version=$version"
}

task release(dependsOn: 'distribution') << {
    println('Doing release build')
}

android.libraryVariants.all { variant ->

    task("generate${variant.name}Javadoc", type: Javadoc) {
        title = "Android Beacon Library $version API"
        description "Generates Javadoc for $variant.name."
        source = variant.javaCompile.source
        ext.androidJar =
                "${android.sdkDirectory}/platforms/${android.compileSdkVersion}/android.jar"
        classpath = files(variant.javaCompile.classpath.files, ext.androidJar)
        options.linksOffline "http://d.android.com/reference/", "${android.sdkDirectory}/docs/reference"
        exclude '**/BuildConfig.java'
        exclude '**/R.java'
    }

}

task generateJavadoc(type: Javadoc, dependsOn: project.configurations.doclava) {
    failOnError = true
    title = null
    source = android.sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs
    options.doclet = "com.google.doclava.Doclava"
    options.docletpath = configurations.doclava.files.asType(List)
    classpath +=
            project.files(android.getBootClasspath().join(File.pathSeparator)) + configurations.compile

    destinationDir = file("../javadocs/")
}

build.mustRunAfter clean

apply from: 'gradle/credentials.gradle'
apply from: 'gradle/compile.gradle'
apply from: 'gradle/publishing.gradle'
apply from: 'gradle/bintray.gradle'
apply from: 'gradle/artifactory.gradle'

artifactoryPublish {
    // Skip deploying to artifactory if building a pull request
    onlyIf { !isSnapPullRequest }
}
```

**`build.gradle` of my fresh new project**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.absense"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {



        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation project(':alt')
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to compile the Android Beacon Library as source linked with your project, its easiest if you have a two-tier project setup like this (assuming your project is name "beacon":

```
beacon
  gradle.properties
  build.gradle
  app
    build.gradle
```

1. Clone the Android Beacon Library repository inside the beacon folder above:

   ```
   git clone https://github.com/AltBeacon/android-beacon-library.git
   ```

   This should give you a structure like this:

   ```
   beacon
     settings.gradle
     build.gradle
     app
       build.gradle
     android-beacon-library
   ```
2. Change your project's settings.gradle file to look like this (add the first line):

   ```
   include ':android-beacon-library'
   include ':app'
   ```
3. Edit the dependencies section of app/build.gradle to look like this:

   ```
   dependencies {
     ...
     compile project(':android-beacon-library')
   }
   ```

You can see an example of this setup in the library [reference application](https://github.com/AltBeacon/android-beacon-library-reference), although parts 2 and 3 are commented out to force the library to load from JCenter.  If you wish to try it with the reference, simply uncomment those lines, and comment out the line like this: `compile 'org.altbeacon:android-beacon-library:2+'`